# Pagination in react using React Hooks and Pagination by MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, material-ui

Consider the following code:

```
 const [currentPage , setCurrentPage] = useState(2)
 const [previousPage , setPreviousPage] = useState(0)



 const handlePageChange = (event , value) =>{
        console.log(value);
        setCurrentPage(previousPage+value)
        setPreviousPage(previousPage+value)
    }

return(
     {panels && panels.slice(previousPage,currentPage).filter((panel)=> panel.circlePrivacy == 'Public' ).map((panel)=>(
                        <div className='garden-card' >
                    <img className='wave-top' src={top} alt='img' />
                    <h1 className='circle-h1' >Circle Name: Tulip</h1>
                    <div className='garden-main-card' >
                        <div className='garden-image-section' >
                            <img src={panel.circleImage} width='300px' className='garden-img' alt='img' />
                            <h1 className='traditional-susu' >Traditional Susu</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className='garden-detail-section' >
                            <h2>Circle Name: {panel.panelName}</h2>
                            <p>Circle Owner:{panel.panelOwnerName}</p>
                            <p>Circle Start Date: {panel.circleStartDate} </p>
                            <p>Plan: {panel.panelPlan} </p>
                            <p>Circle Privacy: {} </p>
                            <p>Cycle Amount: {Math.ceil(panel.giftingAmount / panel.panelMemberCount)} </p>
                            <p>Gifting Amount: {panel.giftingAmount} </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='joining-section' >
                        <button className='joining-flower-btn' >Join Flower</button>
                        <div className='reward-section' >
                            <h2>2000 USD</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <img className='wave-bottom' src={bottom} alt='img' />
                </div>
                    ))
                }
                <div style={{height:100 , backgroundColor:'white', overflow:'hidden',display:'flex',alignItems:'center' , flexDirection:'column'}} >
                <Pagination count={Math.ceil(panels?.length/2)} color='primary' shape='rounded' style={{margin:'auto' , backgroundColor:'white', marginTop:50}} onChange={handlePageChange} />
)
```

What I want to do is to show two items per page. MaterialUI pagination has a function that I passed and has two params event and value.

But I cannot make any progress ahead because whenever I try to execute it, the whole page disappears. Any idea how can I implement it????

Comment: Your second `useState()` hook should use array destructuring rather than object destructuring. Could you clarify why you store the `previousPage` in state in addition to `currentPage`?

Comment: I was just playing around with the state. Truth be told, I have no idea how to achieve this. Can you clarify your solution with a code snippet??

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but the first thing that jumps out is line 2. Notice how you've used curly braces instead of square brackets. Also, if you slice before filtering, I believe you could end up with empty pages (though the pagination controls should still be visible).

Comment: I have updated the code as well as moved slice after filtering. Now what exactly is to be done next.

Comment: The problem is not very clear from the code you've posted. I have noticed a few more things. To get to a specific page, you only need the to know the page number and the number of items per page (i.e., you don't need `previousPage` to calculate the items on the current page). Also, I believe pagination treats the first page as `1` instead of `0`. Are there any errors being thrown or warnings being shown in something like Chrome DevTools?